# Python: How can I assert the origin of a closure?

Tags: python

How can I assert that a returned function originates from the outer function?

```py
def wraps(val):
    def func():
        return val
    return func

a = wraps(5)
# assert that a comes from wraps()
```

I can see that `a.__qualname__` includes the name of the global func: `wraps.<locals>.func`, so I can test based on that, but is that The Right Way™️?

As an extension of the above point, given that the `__qualname__` attrib includes the name of the enclosing function, does that mean there is a ref to it buried somewhere, or would that string be generated at the time the function is created and stored against it with the ref to the outer func discarded at that time?

Comment: I think, the right way is to test that the function does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: What do you gain by asserting that a function is a function, you should test it's functionality?

Comment: Interesting problem, can you specify why you want this? Or is it just for research?

Comment: The question is out of curiosity more than anything. I'm playing around with caching result of expensive func calls which return nothing if they run successfully or raise. I wrote a closure like `wrap(e): def f(): raise e; return f` to repeatedly raise the same exception on subsequent calls if the original run raises. Which led me to try to test the identity of the attribute where I'm storing the cached result func. But it's correct to say that I'm more interested that it repeatedly raises the exc, not what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do that because the function is built, in each `wraps` call:

```
>>> a = wraps(1)
>>> b = wraps(1)
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
139880648604800
>>> id(b)
139880648604936
```

The solution would be to return to the actual base case and have it outside and return a `partial` of it:

```
def func(val):
    return val

from functools import partial
def wraps(val):
    return partial(func, val)
```

That way it is available for assertion wherever you need.

```
>>> f = wraps(10)
>>> f.func
<function func at 0x7f38805efd90>
>>> assert f.func is func
>>> assert f.func is not func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Comment: WRT your first example, I understand that, and I was careful to use my words correctly. I was asking if there is a way to assert it's origin. But your second example does do what I'm asking. I'll have a mess around with it, thanks!

Comment: When I access `a.__qualname__` the name of the enclosing function is in the string that is returned, `'wraps.<locals>.func'`, so I was curious if that meant that a ref to the enclosing func is retained somewhere, of perhaps that string is generated at construction time and the ref to the enclosing func discarded.

Comment: I cannot reply to that exactly. But It feels like it is parsed so it knows that there **will** live a function. As I explained that function is constructed by python in each of the wraps function calls, so each time is a different function, even if it behaves the same.

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: You are welcome, it was an interesting question @SuperShoot!

Comment: If you're interested I posted an answer regarding whether the `__qualname__` is generated on access from a reference to the outer function Spoiler: it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically addressing whether the value of `__qualname__` is lazily generated (and therefore a reference to the enclosing function would have to be retained) or if it is set in advance and therefore no ref to the enclosing function would need to be retained:

> `PyObject* PyFunction_New(PyObject *code, PyObject *globals)` Return
>   value: New reference. Return a new function object associated with the
>   code object code. globals must be a dictionary with the global
>   variables accessible to the function.
>
> The function’s docstring and name are retrieved from the code object.
>   `__module__` is retrieved from globals. The argument defaults, annotations and closure are set to NULL. `__qualname__` is set to the
>   same value as the function’s name.
>
> `PyObject* PyFunction_NewWithQualName(PyObject *code, PyObject
>   *globals, PyObject *qualname)` Return value: New reference. As PyFunction_New(), but also allows setting the function object’s
>   `__qualname__` attribute. qualname should be a unicode object or NULL; if NULL, the `__qualname__` attribute is set to the same value as its
>   `__name__` attribute.

This clearly demonstrates that the value of `__qualname__` is set to a unicode value at function creation time and as such the presence of the scoping functions name in the qualname doesn't mean there is a reference to the outer function retained.

Comment: This is really interesting indeed!

Comment: [PEP 3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/). In there they mention that it could be done for functions nested in classes in Python 2 (don't mention nested functions though), but capability was removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you define your close function the same way you defined your non-closure one you can definitely assert

```
def wraps():
    def func():
        pass
    return func

a = wraps
assert a is wraps
```

You can achieve the above only by defining func outside like so

```
from functools import partial

def func(val):
    return val

def wraps(val):
    return partial(func, val)

a = wraps(10)
#Assertion is successful

#A can be called directly
print(a())
#10

#Assertion with qualname
assert a.func.__qualname__ == 'func'
```

In your original question, `__qualname__` can be use for assertion like so

```
def wraps(val):
    def func():
        return val
    return func

a = wraps(10)
assert a.__qualname__ == 'wraps.<locals>.func'
```

According to the docs: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.**qualname**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__)

Qualified name above makes sense since it tells us that we have a function `func` inside `wraps` which is local to it

Comment: But the difference is that I'm calling `wraps` in the second case: `a = wraps(5)`

Comment: Can I ask you what does `# assert that a comes from wraps()` means @SuperShoot ?

Comment: I want to verify the identity of the function that produced the function stored in `a`.

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, please check! @SuperShoot

Comment: I think wraps would have to return `partial(func, val)` for the ops to be equivalent.

Comment: Updated with assertion using `__qualname__` as well! @SuperShoot

Comment: accessing `__qualname__` isn't a requisite, I'm more interested in knowing if a reference to `wraps` exists accessible through the closure. The fact that the wrapper func name is available in the qualname of the closure is what makes me curious about it.

Comment: That's what a qualname, or a qualified name is supposed to tell us right, check my updated answer for why the qualname is that way @SuperShoot

Comment: I think you're missing my point, but that's OK. Thanks for contributing:)

Comment: Okay, guess I need to learn more about these things, can I atleast get an upvote for whatever I was able to contribute @SuperShoot

Comment: Okay, guess I need to learn more about these things, can I atleast get an upvote frm you for whatever I was able to contribute @SuperShoot